# Multi-level class inheritance with inconsistent constructors

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, multi-level

I have 3 classes that derive from one another - GameScreen is the base class to which MenuScreen is derived from. I then have a third class 'TitleScreen' which derives from 'MenuScreen'.

The flow is basically from the base class: 'GameScreen' -> 'MenuScreen' -> 'TitleScreen'

The base class 'GameScreen' has no parameters in it's constructor, like wise with 'TitleScreen', however I need a parameter for 'MenuScreen'. I currently have the header files as:

GameScreen.h

```
class GameScreen
{
public:
    GameScreen();
}
```

MenuScreen.h

```
class MenuScreen : public GameScreen
{
public:
    MenuScreen(std::string title);
}
```

TitleScreen.h

```
class TitleScreen : public MenuScreen
{
public:
    TitleScreen(std::string title) : MenuScreen(title);
}
```

What I'm having difficulty trying to understand is if this is possible in C++ (I'm following a C# sample for Game State Management which does this). Reading through class inheritance in some books I have it only covers parameters inherited from the base class, were as my sample base class has no parameters.

Comment: Yes, it works exactly as you have written - except that you should call the MenuScreen constructor in the actual implementation, not in the declaration of the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are missing `;` after each class declaration.
2. If you write `TitleScreen(std::string title) : MenuScreen(title)` you are defining the body of the method but the body is missing... so you should put just declaration to your TitleScreen.h :

   ```
   class TitleScreen : public MenuScreen
   {
   public:
       TitleScreen(std::string title);
   };
   ```

   and then place the body of the constructor to TitleScreen.cpp:

   ```
   #include "TitleScreen.h"

   TitleScreen::TitleScreen(std::string title) : MenuScreen(title)
   {
       // ..
   }
   ```

Edit: fixed the terminology accordint to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration).

Comment: You are confusing declaration with definition terminology. And it is also worth mentioning that both can go together as in C#, or separately as in your example, possibly with pros and cons.